# Can GameGardian Hack a React Native Game

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

I have created a Money Game using React Native. In this game, there are two variables: Score and Increment. The initial value of Score is set to 10, and Increment is set to 5 at the beginning of the game. Every 3 seconds, the Score increases by the value of the Increment variable. For instance, if the Score is 10, after three seconds, it will become 15 as it has been incremented by the value stored in the Increment variable. This process continues, increasing the Score to 20, 25, and so on.

In order to ensure the persistent storage of game data, I have implemented a feature where the game data is saved in the async storage every time the Score changes due to the Increment variable. This way, the progress and achievements of the players are securely stored and can be resumed whenever needed.

However, when attempting to modify the game using GameGuardian, I noticed that it provides incorrect values. I am curious to understand why this happens. Is it because React Native has built-in protection mechanisms for these programs?

I have attempted to hack various games, but interestingly, only this particular game seems to be immune to hacking attempts. Surprisingly, I have not implemented any security measures for this game.

Comment: How are you managing the data storage exactly? Can you share that code?